# Inserting values in database through PHP form

Tags: php, mysql, post, pdo

I've the following code in my file:

```
$s.='<form method="post">';
$s.='NAME: <input type="text" name="name" id="name" /><br>';
$s.='Email: <input type="text" name="email" id="email" /><br>';
$s.='Comment:<br />';
$s.='<textarea name="comment" id="comment" /></textarea><br>';
$s.='<input type="hidden" name="articleid" id="articleid" value="' . $id . '" />';
$s.='<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />';
$s.='</form>';
if(isset($_POST['submit'])&&$_POST['submit']=='Submit'){
    $table = 'comment';
    $row = array(
            'blog_id' => $_POST['articleid'],
            'name' => $_POST['name'],
            'email' => $_POST['email'],
            'comment' => $_POST['comment']
            );
    $x = pdoQuick::getManager()->insert($row, $table);
    header('location: example.com/xyz ');
}
```

The `insert ()` I'm using from [here](https://github.com/techjacker/PDO-Quick)

The `id` that I'm using in `articleid` hidden field is not posing any problem. The problem is somewhere else.

The values in my database table `comment` are not inserted.

Comment: any error message... ?

Comment: Do check whether PDO returns any sql errors.

Comment: @ThomasHaratyk: I can't find any errors. The above github repo provides a feature to log errors in a file. But there aren't any errors in that file.

Comment: @PalakArora First thing, your `$s.='<form method="post">';` shouldn't first start off with a `dot`. Only the subsequents. Unless you have more above it that you didn't post. It should read as `$s='<form method="post">';` - Remove the dot, and get back to me.

Comment: @Fred Yup otherwise it will throw 'undefined variable error"

Comment: @Fred : `$s` variable concats a long HTML content, and this is all part of a `php` file.

Comment: @PalakArora Also, your `)&&$_POST` is all crunched up. Make it breathe... as in `) && $_POST`.

Comment: @Fred: ^^What difference will that make?

Comment: @PalakArora It's just the "usual" way of `coding`. You're giving it "room" for errors.

Comment: @Fred: Well, if there were any "room" for "such" errors, wouldn't there be a `parse error`..? You don't think that I posted a question here, without having thought of such aspects as you are suggesting.

Comment: Make sure you haven't echoed anything before `header()`.

Comment: @LuigiSiri: No..the `echo` comes about 20-30 lines after the `header()`

Comment: degug - `print "\nrow successfully inserted with id $x\n";`  `print_r($row);`

Comment: @PalakArora Oh, you may very well be right on that point, sure. However, when I code, is better to read and symbols could often get mistaken for another. Sometimes one could be looking forever to find a character that's been "doubled", where it should've been the other way around. It's just good practice, that's all. Personally, I don't like being **squeezed in** while waiting in line at the supermarket. Unless they're all good looking women!

Comment: @amigura: `row successfully inserted with id 0 Array ( [blog_id] => 55 [name] => oivnhoihv [email] => ovioivvnh [comment] => ofivnhodivnhbeosi )`

Comment: @PalakArora I don't know if this will make a difference or not, but there is no `action` set for your form. Which way are you using to handle your form?

Comment: @Fred: `action` is used when I want to send data to another file. In the above question, I'm not sending data to any other file. I'm inserting data there only and using a `header` afterwards.

Comment: @PalakArora Ah, ok. And did you keep `name="submit"` as `Nelson` stated below (`<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />';`) ? I believe that's an important piece to have, whether it's related to your problem or not.

Comment: What's the output from `print_r($_POST)`?

Comment: @LuigiSiri: `Array ( [name] => myname [email] => myemail [comment] => xxxxxxxx [articleid] => 6 [submit] => Submit )`

Comment: @Fred debug returns results so updated form must be ok. everthing looks ok.

Comment: @PalakArora I may be picking at straws here, but what if you tried `$table = '$comment';` instead of `$table = 'comment';`?

Comment: @amigura Yes, I saw that just now, thank you.

Comment: @Fred: The table's name is `'comment'`. Its not a variable containing the string `comment`. Instead the name of the table itself is `comment`.

Comment: @PalakArora Like I said, I was *Picking at straws*. Maybe the problem lies elsewhere then? I can't see anything else that is problematic in your (posted) code. Could be something inside an included file, if you have one (not posted), or the way it's being inserted inside the database itself. (INSERT INTO...etc) - Sorry, I couldn't be of more help. I wish you well.

Comment: Did you followed [PDO-Quick installation](https://github.com/techjacker/PDO-Quick#installation)?

Comment: @LuigiSiri: Ya. I followed them. Many functions are working. Its just that this insert isn't working. Although I guess I found the problem [here](https://github.com/techjacker/PDO-Quick/blob/master/pdoquick.php#L160). When I print `$vals`, it doesn't contain the values that I'd POSTED. I'm trying to work on it now. 
If possible, try to help me with it.

Comment: For example, here is the output I get for `$cols= blog_id, name, email, comment` and `$vals= :blog_id, :name, :email, :comment`. So basically, the `$sql = INSERT INTO comment ( blog_id, name, email, comment ) values ( :blog_id, :name, :email, :comment )`

Comment: @PalakArora Maybe there's a conflict with your database table `comment` (if that's what you meant by "table") and `:comment`?

Answer (score 2):

You should give a name to your submit button, if you pretend to retrieve it from php like `$_POST['submit']` , like this:

```
$s.='<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />';
                              ^----- YOU FORGOT THIS
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably not what you want to hear but i would say in the time you spent here and trying to solve the problem yourself, it might benefit you more to learn PDO then you would not have to reliant on someone else's code that should of worked for you in theory. The basics of PDO can be easy to learn within a hour no joke. my 2 cents.

Try to see if code below works for you.

```
$db=new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test;","root","password");

$sql = "INSERT INTO comment (blog_id,name,email,comment) VALUES (:blog_id,:name,:email,:comment)";
$ami = $db->prepare($sql);
$ami->execute(array(
        ':blog_id' => $_POST['articleid'],
        ':name' => $_POST['name'],
        ':email' => $_POST['email'],
        ':comment' => $_POST['comment']
        ));

print_r($ami->errorInfo()); // debug
```

http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php